# Fix my layout to have correct margins with css

Tags: css

I am trying to make a layout that looks like this:

```
------------------------------
|    _|_________________|_    |
|   |content, content,    |   |
|---|  content, content,  |---|
|   |    content, content,|   |
|   |  content, content,  |   |
|   |content, content,    |   |
|   |  content, content,  |   |
|   |    content, content,|   |
|---|  .................  |---|
|   |_____________________|   |
|     |                 |     |
-------------------------------
```

This is what I managed to come up with so far.....

The margin-top and bottom isn't what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
html, body { height:100% }
#content { width:80%; min-width:600px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10%; margin-bottom:10%; background:#CCCCCC; overflow:auto }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id='content'>
content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a few educated guesses here:

- I see `height: 100%`, and you're obviously trying to horizontally center `<div id='content'>`.
- So, that picture is the whole window, and you want it to scale when the window is resized.
- I also see `min-width: 600px`, so you want there to be a minimum width (and height?).
- `overflow: auto` - either you're preparing to clear floats, or you're trying to make it scroll if the content is too long.
- I'm not sure what the four boxes are supposed to be doing.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/araqe5) ([edit](http://jsbin.com/araqe5/edit))

Comment: This is close enough to what I want.

Comment: This will work in "all modern browsers". I even quickly checked IE6, and it looks correct there also.

Answer (score 1):

why you can't try the margin in pixels?

```
margin:10px
```

or

```
margin:10px 11px 12px 13px;
```

top right bottom left correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code to JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/RpWpN/1/

I added `height:80%;` this seems to achieve what you are after.